# Application of Newton's laws : A system of three blocks

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

[image]

This is a question from my physics coursebook. Everything in the picture should be self-explanatory. Pulley and string are massless. There is friction between contact surfaces of block A and block C ($\mu$ = $\mu_s$ = $\mu_k$). Rest of the surfaces are frictionless. Mass of both A and B is 1kg. Mass of C is 4kg.

According to the textbook, correct answer is 30 ≤ F ≤ 90

I need help with this. I solved it and I can't figure out why I am getting an incorrect answer. I cross-checked my answer by plugging in a value less than $30N$ for $F$, and $f$ comes out to be greater than $5$ which is not possible so I understand that $F$ can't be less than $30$. Similarly I put a value greater than $60$ for $F$ and $f$ came out to be negative. What does it mean? Does a negative value of $f$ show that $F$ must indeed be less than $60$ for the three blocks to move with the same acceleration?

I have another question. For this system of these three blocks, if I apply a force of $80N$ to block C, is it possible to predict the acceleration of the three blocks? Can we find out their accelerations for a value of the applied force, say $80N$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the friction force $f$ becomes negative is no problem at all, it just means that the friction is pushing the block forward, instead of holding it back. And since the friction limit is the same for pushing than for pulling, it is not surprising that the equilibrium (when the force vanishes) is right in the middle of the two extremes ($F=60$): at $F=30$ block A is about to slide forward, due to the weight of B. At $F=90$ the block is about to slide backwards, due to block C accelerating too fast.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes sense. I understand it now. Why does the inequality $0$ ≤ $f$ ≤  $f_{s,max}$ not give me complete information? Do I have to analyse it separately?

Comment: Because it is the absolute value of the friction force what is limited. The correct expression is $-f_{\text{max} \leq f \leq -f_{\text{max}$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $-f_{\text{max}} \leq f \leq f_{\text{max}}$

Comment: thanks a lot, again. It helped